# What is the difference between "traceEvent" and "traceMarker"?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

The `Debug.Trace` module has the [`traceEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#g:2) function that emits a message to the eventlog. Recently, a `traceMarker` function has been added that seems to do the same thing. For example, take the following program:

```
module Main where

import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = do
    traceEventIO "This is an event"
    traceMarkerIO "This is a marker"
```

Compiled with `-debug -w -eventlog -rtsopts` and executed with `+RTS -vu`, it shows the following in the eventlog:

```
...
cap 0: running thread 1 (ThreadRunGHC)
cap 0: This is an event
cap 0: User marker: This is a marker
cap 0: thread 1 stopped (finished)
cap 0: created thread 2
...
```

When to use `traceEvent` and when to use `traceMarker`?

Comment: `traceMarker` creates bookmarks and big vertical lines in ThreadScope. `traceEvent` only shows up in the (noisy) 'Instant Events' channel in ThreadScope (I think), and it is used by ghc-events-analyze.

Comment: If you could make a screenshot of the difference in ThreadScope, probably this would make for a good accepted answer!